# Comparing Tables in Delphi without SQL

Tags: database, delphi, delphi-7

I'm having problems while using Tables in a Paradox Data Base in Delphi.

I need to compare two tables and verify which fields are identical and which are different. At the end, both tables must contain the same values on the fields.

However, everything must be done without using SQL, only pure Delphi.

Here is the code so far, but I'm not getting the expected result:

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject); 
  var  
  s1,s2:string;  
begin  
  Table1.First;  
  while not (Table1.Eof) do  
  Begin 
      s1 := Table1.FieldByName('Campo').AsString; 
      Table2.First; 
      while not (Table2.Eof) do 
      Begin 
          s2 := Table2.FieldByName('Campo').AsString; 

          if (s1 <> s2) then 
          begin 
            Table2.Append; 
            Table2.FieldByName('Campo').AsString := 
                Table1.FieldByName('Campo').AsString; 
          end 
          else if (s1 = s2) then 
          begin 
            Table2.Next; 
          end; 

          Table2.Next; 
      End; 
      Table1.Next;  
  End;
End;
```

Comment: Would have been useful if you were more specific about the "not getting the expected result" part. How is what you get different from your expectations? I don't see `Table2.Post` matching `Table.Append` in your code.

Comment: Some duplicated fields are created when I use this code. And where should I put the Table.Append? I've tried it but I'm getting an error.

Comment: Never tell people you ask for help what the error is. We love to guess.

Comment: Why would you need to have two identical tables??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make two passes to copy missing data from one table into the other. The easiest way is to just create a procedure to do it for you, and then call it twice:

```
procedure TForm1.CopyData(const Src, Dest: TTable);
var
  CompareVal: string;
begin
  Src.First;
  while not Src.Eof do
  begin
    CompareVal := Src.FieldByName('Campo').AsString;
    if not Dest.Locate('Campo', CompareVal, []) then
    begin
      Dest.Insert;     // Or Dest.Append;
      Dest.FieldByName('Campo').AsString := CopmareVale;
      Dest.Post;
    end;
    Src.Next;
  end;
end;
```

Call it like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CopyData(Table1, Table2);
  CopyData(Table2, Table1);
end;
```

This works fine if the databases aren't really large. If they are, you can improve performance by adding indexes on the fields that you're comparing. See the Delphi help for [`TDataSet.Locate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Using_Indexes_to_Search_for_Records), which has more info and some links to other topics that might help. (Link is to current Delphi help, but the info is applicable to Delphi 7 as well for the most part.)

Comment: This answer is OK as far as it goes but ignores minor matters like primary keys. The solution would be fine if the table had only one field but in real life, this is only a partial solution (although it is based on the question which also ignores such problems).

Comment: @No'amNewman: Yep. The question didn't ask for a basic education on using databases (which would be out of scope for an answer here). It asked a specific question about making the illustrated code work to get two matching copies of the data. Without more info, it's about the only answer that can be provided. If the poster has different requirements after this, then a new question should be posted to ask that question. :-)

Comment: You don't really need two passes if you know how to code a balance line algorithm as we used to do all the time way back when I coded COBOL... :-) But you do need to know which fields are considered the keys. These don't need to be keys in rDB terms, it works on sequential data sets just as well.

Comment: @Marjan: You can also do it much more easily using SQL, which was ruled out as a possibility. Feel free to write a BLA to answer this question, though. :-)

Comment: Nah, don't have the stomach for a BLA at the moment :-) (Cold is dampening brain waves). Would like a hint / link at the SQL solution though. It's been some time since I worked extensively with SQL and need to read up on stuff that goes beyond the basic CRUD statements.

Comment: @Marjan: You can do an `INSERT...WHERE NOT EXISTS()`, or an `INSERT` with an `OUTER JOIN` and `CASE` statements. Some DBMSs support `MERGE`, which will either `INSERT` or `UPDATE` based on whether a match is found.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. It solved my problem because the DataBase is very simple and does not contain any primary keys.

Answer (score -1):

Read through all records of `Table2` and put `Table2.FieldByName('Campo').AsString` values in a sorted `TStringList`. Then iterate through the records of `Table1` and check `stringList.IndexOf` for  all `Table1.FieldByName('Campo').AsString`. When `IndexOf` returns -1, append record to `Table2`. Switch `Table1` and `Table2` and repeat.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But is there some way in which I wouldn't need to use TStringList?

Comment: No `SQL`, no `TStringList` - the next thing to ask is how to do it without code.

Comment: -1. This is the wrong solution. You have a database that has the capability of searching - why move data out of it to do what the database is designed to do?

Comment: @KenWhite - You want to get into indices and `Locate`? - go ahead.

Comment: There's no index needed for `Locate`, and it works fine if you're not dealing with very large databases. If you have lots of data, you should already have indexes. Either way, moving from the database into a `TStringList` to compare with values in the database is unnecessary overhead. Either way, you have a pass through the source data once; with the `TStringList` you have the extra overhead of storing it all in memory.